# Passing a Javascript variable to CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I like to keep my code separated as best practices tend to dictate. As such, I have the following problem line of code in Javascript:

`x[i].firstChild.innerHTML = remain;`

This works perfectly but breaks my rule of editing presentation in Javascript. I want to instead pass `@remain` to CSS and add a class to the `x[i]` element I'm referencing. In the class, the contents will be changed but I'm not sure how to reference a JS variable in CSS.

In short, if in JS, I make a variable x, how can I reference that value in CSS.

If it matters (probably shouldn't), all languages are in different files.

Comment: You could instead have @remain as a calculated value that you place within a very specific element. KnockoutJS makes this connection between HTML and JavaScript much easier but still maintains a pretty good barrier between the two.

That said, the barrier between JavaScript and HTML is breaking down very quickly with the adoption of ReactJS and JSX so just something to think about your notions of why you want to keep them separated.

Comment: I understand that things can and will change but for now accessibility is a large part of my platform. By that I mean that for now, everyone that has basic web design practice can follow my code very easily (especially employers), which helps me a lot. When I don't need anyone to read my code, more niche practices can be employed. But your comment does give me something to think about when it comes to direction.

Comment: Your rule seems a bit arbitrary, that you don't want to set the HTML content from JS, but you do want to reference a JS variable from CSS. If anything that seems *worse*, because CSS is just supposed to style the content, not to set the text of the content. Also, updating the text of an HTML element from JS is pretty normal practice, so I wouldn't describe the code you're trying to avoid as problematic. (How do you set the text of an element from CSS?)

Comment: In short, you can't with CSS as it is not a dynamic language. It would be a differenct story with some LESS or similar engines.